# What's the preferred way to assign a collection from a parameter in Android?

Tags: java, android

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369693/whats-the-preferred-way-to-assign-a-collection-from-a-parameter) brings up the issues surrounding code like the following (copied from that question):

```
public MyClass {
    public void initialize(Collection<String> data) {
        this.data = data; // <-- Bad!
    }
    private Collection<String> data;
}
```

Storing a reference opens up doors to bugs through accidentally injecting data into the private field `data`. The accepted answer by Aaron Digulla suggests a policy of freezing sets with `Collection.setUnmodifiable(set);` before passing it around, but he mentions that the tradeoff is a performance hit, as anybody who wants to modify the collection needs to copy it, change it, and then save it back.

Are there any best practices when dealing with this in extremely resource-limited Android environments?

Comment: Seems like the best approach is not to mutate Collections after using them in this way.  Maybe this can be encouraged through documentation and comments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, just keep the reference. One android app doesn't contain too many codes, and you or your dev team controls all the source code. So the simplest solution works for most situations.

Comment: +1 This is the best answer; if people on your team start messing around with your encapsulated data, kick them in the rear and tell them to learn to code properly.