# Assignment to interface-defined collection in Java

Tags: java, collections

**The problem**

I use code inspection in my project and it has the specific collection assignment rule:

```
Assignment to Collection field 'this.wildcards' from parameter 'wildcards' at line XX
```

Which is understandable, the tip states quite clear - since the collection can be mutated outside of the object after assignment, it would be an implicit state modification that can cause lots of bugs which are difficult to detect.

Now, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369693/whats-the-preferred-way-to-assign-a-collection-from-a-parameter) where some options to resolve are suggested. In my case a shallow copy might be the easiest option since I know that the collection is quite simple and it's creation is a plain operation.

**The question**

My question is - what if I defined the collection member as an interface (like most likely it would be done)? There's a potential problem that I see here. For instance, my collection is a `Map<>` but to do shallow copy I would need to define exact type there, like `HashMap<>` - so I will potentially lie to the user of the class that I accept `Map<>` since in fact, I use one specific implementation of it. And if user will decide not to use `HashMap<>` but something else .. you got the idea.

**Considered thoughts**

I can of course narrow down type and explicitly say that I wish to use `HashMap<>` - but it's something I don't want to do with the one and only reason of the collection safe initialization. Besides, I really don't use any `HashMap<>` - specific stuff in the class logic, so it would be a waste to set the type precisely.

So what could be my options? What is the best way to achieve both safe copy + not narrowing down the member collection type because of that?

*Edit: I use Java8 if that matters*

Comment: I think this heavily depends on what exactly you're going to do with the stored collection. E.g. is there also a corresponding "get" method? (The main differentiation here is IMHO whether it's "List-like" or "Set-like", i.e. whether elements may appear multiple times or only once). For `Map`, it may be even more tricky, because passing in a sorted map (`TreeMap`) may imply some assumptions by the caller. Storing it as a `HashMap` could break this expectation. (BTW: I hardly **ever** use `HashMap`. In most cases, `LinkedHashMap` is "safer" in this regard).

Comment: No, I know which "type" of the collection is incoming. So it's `Map` for instance (and I know that it should be `Map`, not `Collection`). But still those types are interfaces and therefore I can not just straight instantiate the object to copy it as I don't know the certain type that would be used on call

Comment: (Some confusion may arise here, because you talked about "collections", and later about `Map`, although `Map` is not a `Collection`. However, I tried to point out the general question about *what* you are doing with this thing (regardless of whether it's a `Collection` or a `Map`), and that there may be different caveats for the `Collection` and the `Map` case)

Comment: Yes, not best words choice from my side. I used word "collection" to point to some entity which is collection in "common sense", not `Collection` as Java type. So yes - I'm aware that `Map` and `Collection` are different and in certain class I use either one or another.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making it so complicated on yourself? Just use [`putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)), which is available on `Map`:

```
public void initialize(final Map<K, V> wildcards) {
    this.wildcards.clear();
    this.wildcards.putAll(wildcards);
}
```

While it still narrows down the implementations of Map you can use for your instance field, it's just those that support `putAll`... IIRC **all** java API implementations support that operation...

Comment: It will be an NPE to call something on the collection that isn't yet created. Note that `this.wildcards` is a member which I try to initialize. Thus I need first to create it before calling anything on it. And so if I will initialize it, I will again need to do that with some certain type which implements `Map` and it leads to same issue I've described in the question

Comment: If you try to initialize a member use a damned constructor. Why would you have to take special care in which implementation of Map you choose to initialize that field with?

Comment: I use the damned constructor. And what will I write there? (I want to fulfill the contract and so if I declared that constructor accepts `Map` then it must work with __any__ implementation of it)

Comment: Please drop by in the Java room again... I have no clue wtf your problem is. And comments are not intended for this back and forth :/